# tf.function decorator on body of tf.while_loop throwing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, decorator

I am using Tensorflow v1.14. I am building a `tf.while_loop()` with two functions `body` and `condition`. I need to print the number of times each function is executed. I use the decorator `tf.function` for both `body` and `condition`. When the decorator is placed on `body` there's always an error and on the `condition` method it works just fine. Here's the code to replicate the issue.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=1, dynamic_size=True, clear_after_read=True)
i = tf.constant(0)


@tf.function
def body(j, a):
    tf.print("Body ", j)
    a = a.write(j, 5)
    return [tf.add(j, 1), a]


@tf.function
def condition(j, _):
    tf.print("Condition ", j)
    return tf.less(j, 5)


_, a = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i, a])
c = a.stack()
print(tf.Session().run(a))
```

If the decorator is removed from the `body` method, the code executes successfully.

The error I get with the above code is

```
    _, a = tf.while_loop(condition, body, [i, a])
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3501, in while_loop
    return_same_structure)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 3012, in BuildLoop
    pred, body, original_loop_vars, loop_vars, shape_invariants)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/control_flow_ops.py", line 2937, in _BuildLoop
    body_result = body(*packed_vars_for_body)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 414, in __call__
    self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializer_map)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 357, in _initialize
    *args, **kwds))
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1349, in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected
    graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1652, in _maybe_define_function
    graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1545, in _create_graph_function
    capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 715, in func_graph_from_py_func
    func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 307, in wrapped_fn
    return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
  File "/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py", line 705, in wrapper
    raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(type(e))
AssertionError: in converted code:

    tensorflow_functions/src/delete.py:454 body
        a = a.write(j, 5)
    .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py:1191 write
        return self._implementation.write(index, value, name=name)
    .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/tf_should_use.py:193 wrapped
        return _add_should_use_warning(fn(*args, **kwargs))
    .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py:298 write
        colocate_with_first_write_call=self._colocate_with_first_write_call)
    .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py:1086 __init__
        name=name)
    .local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/tensor_array_ops.py:471 __init__
        assert handle is None

    AssertionError:
```

Why is this happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi.. Is your issue resolved. If so, please share the solution so that it will be useful for the community. If not, while trying to reproduce your error, I am facing the error, `TypeError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.ops.tensor_array_ops.TensorArray object at 0x7f21764072e8> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.tensor_array_ops.TensorArray'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a TensorArray into a Tensor or Operation.)`. Please help us reproduce your error. Thanks!